# having PL/SQL troubles

Tags: sql, plsql

The question reads as follows. Create a procedure, named FIND_DISCOUNT, that receives the number of seats booked as an input parameter and returns the discount percentage through a output parameter. Use the discount table to retrieve the discount percentage.
The table is as follows; two columns and three rows. Column one: 10 20 30. Column two: 15 20 25.

Now I can create the procedure to simply check against column one and return the amount in column two but I have to take into consideration that the number of seats is not a fixed value e.g: 23 which would mean it's not directly listed in the table but it is more than 20 but less than 30 so discount percentage would be 20%. I have no problem hard coding the values and using if statements to find the output but the question clearly states to use the table and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution which takes the input parameter and compares it to multiple values in a table

Please help I can post additional information if necessary and I'm not asking anyone to give me a solution but to simply show me how I should be thinking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of seats is in the discount table, then you can get the discount percentage using a query such as

```
SELECT discount_percentage
  INTO v_discount_percentage
  FROM your_table
 WHERE number_of_seats = p_number_of_seats;
```

Here, `p_number_of_seats` is the number of seats, which might be a parameter passed into the procedure, and `v_discount_percentage` is a local variable that holds the discount percentage returned.

But what if the number of seats isn't in the table?  In that case, you want to round the number of seats down to the next value in the table.  Essentially, the number of seats that you want to look up is the largest value in the `number_of_seats` column that is no more than `p_number_of_seats`.

I would suggest using two queries:

- one to fetch the largest value in `number_of_seats` no more than `p_number_of_seats`.
- one to look up the discount percentage, using the largest value obtained from the previous query.

Take care also to handle the case where the number of seats is too small to have any discount applied to it.

Comment: Wow thanks this helped a lot. Can't see how I missed it

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try, the solution is too simple.

DISCOUNT TABLE:

COLUMN1 COLUMN2

======= =======

10  15
20  20
30  25

### PROCDURE IS:

```
create or replace procedure FIND_DISCOUNT(p_booked_seats in number,
                                          p_discount     out number) is
  cursor cur_discount is
    select column1, column2 from discount order by 1 ;
begin
  p_discount := 0;
  for rec in cur_discount loop
    if p_booked_seats >= rec.column1 then
      p_discount := rec.column2;
    end if;

  end loop;

end;
```

### PROCEDURE TEST:

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  find_discount(p_booked_seats => :p_booked_seats,
                p_discount => :p_discount);
end;
```